# Should members of a class be turned static when more than one object creation is not needed?

Tags: c++, oop, class, static

```
class AA
{
    public:
        AA ();
        static void a1          ();
        static std :: string b1 ();
        static std :: string c1 (unsigned short x);
};
```

My class won't have different objects interacting with among themselves or with others.
Of course I need to have at least one object to call the functions of this class, so I thought of making the members `static` so that unnecessary object creation can be avoided.

What are the pros and cons of this design? What will be a better design?

Comment: Why even bother with a class at all?

Comment: In your case, i think enums would be a better fit.

Comment: @Pubby then, in which cases do we "need" to have a class?

Comment: @AnishaKaul when you want to create several instances.

Comment: @Pubby then why is the singleton pattern there? It creates one object.

Comment: @AnishaKaul Most uses of "singleton" is when you want deferred initialization or private state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Should members of a class be turned `static` when more than one object creation is not needed?**

You make members of the class `static` when you need only one instance of the member for all objects of your class. When you declare a class member `static` the member becomes per class instead of per object.

When you say you need only one object of your class, You are probably pointing towards the **singleton design pattern**. Note that pattern is widely considered an anti pattern and its usefulness if any is dependent to specific situations.

The reason you mention in Q is no way related to whether you should make a member `static` or not.

Comment: @AnishaKaul `static` is not *singleton design pattern*, but it works as well.

Comment: *"When you say you need only one object of your class, You are probably pointing towards the singleton design pattern. "* That is a great point I missed.

Comment: The reason singleton is an anti-pattern is precisely because it *isn't* the same as only needing one instance of the class. If you only need one instance, only create one instance. What Singleton does is enforce that you only *can* create one instance, no matter how many you might need, or other clients of your class might need, or how many you might need in future or under test conditions.

Comment: ... basically it's the difference between only needing one, and needing there to only be one. Don't implement the latter just because the former is true.

Answer (score 2):

To access to static members, you don't even need an object, just call

```
AA::a1()
```

This patterns is called "Monostate", the alternative being Singleton, where you actually create an object, but make sure it's only done once, there are tons of tutorials on how to do that, just google it.

Comment: If you are going to have at most 1 object at any time during your programs life, you are talking about singleton, and making it all static is an alternative. If the number is going to go above 1, neither is a good option

Comment: @AnishaKaul Static members don't prevent object creation. For that you need private constructors or pure abstract classes.

Answer (score 1):

Your class has no data members, so I don't see any good reason to use a class at all:

```
namespace AA
{
    void a1          ();
    std :: string b1 ();
    std :: string c1 (unsigned short x);
};
```

> Of course I need to have at least one object to call the functions of this class

That's not true. You can call static member functions without an instance of the class.

A note on the Singleton pattern: it has a bad reputation, it is often mis-used, and in my experience it is only very rarely useful. What it does is enforce that there can only be one instance of the class, and that this instance is globally accessible.

People often think, "I only need one instance, therefore I should use Singleton", especially when Singleton is the first Capitalized Design Pattern they're introduced to. This is wrong -- if you only need one instance, create one instance and use it. Don't unnecessarily limit all future users of the class to only create one instance. Don't unnecessarily create shared global state. Both things make your code less flexible, harder to use in different ways and therefore in particular harder to test. Some people would argue that for these reasons, Singleton is strictly *never* useful.

In this case you don't seem to need even one instance. If that's the case I'd use free functions as above.

Comment: Please put the info of your comment under Als's answer in your answer. I find it valuable.